# Read/download JSON file and store data in a local JSON file via angular 5

Tags: html, json, typescript, angular5, openweathermap

I am trying to read out the JSON file from openweathermap and store it in a local JSON file with the help of angular 5. But for unknown reason to me I get the following message in the browser inspector:

```
core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Error trying to diff 'Rotterdam'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed
```

Not sure what this exactly means and trying to google the issue did find me any solutions. Also when I debug it looks like it can properly read the JSON from openweathermap, but I have the feeling that when I try to subscribe it to my local JSON I am doing something wrong.

Here is the code for the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

import { City } from '../_models/city.model';
import { Search } from '../_models/search.model';
import { variable } from '@angular/compiler/src/output/output_ast';

const API_URL_SEARCH = 'http://localhost:3000/search';
const API_ARGS: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions();
const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
API_ARGS.headers = headers;

@Injectable()
export class CityService {
  searchList: Search[];
  private searchURL = 'http://openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=rotterdam&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22';
  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  getOpenWeatherMap(): Observable<Search[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.searchURL)
                    .map(this.extractData)
                    .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private extractData(res: Response) {
    const body = res.json();
    return body;
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    console.error(error.message || error);
    return Observable.throw(error.message || error);
  }
 }
```

And the code for the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { CityService } from '../_shared/city.service';
import { Search } from '../_models/search.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-city',
  templateUrl: './city.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city.component.css']
})
export class CityComponent implements OnInit {

  searches: Observable<Search[]>;
  searchList: Search[];
  errorMessage: String;
  constructor(private cityService: CityService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searches = this.cityService.getSearches();
  }

  getOpenWeatherMap() {
    // this.cityService.getOpenWeatherMap()
    //                 .subscribe(result => this.searches = this.cityService.getOpenWeatherMap());
    this.searches = this.cityService.getOpenWeatherMap();
    this.searches.subscribe(
      searchList => this.searchList = searchList,
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
}
```

The code for the model:

```
export class Search {
  constructor(
      public coord: Coord,
      public weather: Weather,
      public base: string,
      public main: Main,
      public visability: string,
      public wind: Wind,
      public clouds: Clouds,
      public dt: string,
      public sys: Sys,
      public id: string,
      public name: string,
      public cod: string
  ) {}
}

export class Coord {
  constructor(
      public lon: string,
      public lat: string
  ) {}
}

export class Weather {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public main: string,
    public description: string,
    public icon: string
  ) {}
}

export class Main {
  constructor(
    public temp: string,
    public pressure: string,
    public sea_level: string,
    public humidity: string,
    public temp_min: string,
    public temp_max: string
  ) {}
}

export class Wind {
  constructor(
    public speed: string,
    public deg: string
  ) {}
}

export class Clouds {
  constructor(
    public all: string
  ) {}
}

export class Sys {
  constructor(
    public type: string,
    public message: string,
    public country: string,
    public sunrise: string,
    public sunset: string
  ) {}
}
```

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<div class = "container">
  <h2>Search for city</h2>

    <form>
        <div class = "row" >
          <div class="col-sm-12">
      <label for="cityField">City Name:</label>
      <input class="cityField" #cityField>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="getOpenWeatherMap()">Search</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>

    <div *ngIf="errorMessage"> {{errorMessage}} </div>

    <div class="container">
      <h2>Search</h2>
      <table class="table" style="width:100%">
        <tr>
            <th>City Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>weather</th>
            <th>Temp (°C)</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let Search of searches | async">
              <td>{{Search.name}}</td>
              <td>{{Search.sys.country}}</td>
              <td>{{Search.weather[0].description}}</td>
              <td>{{Search.main.temp}}</td>
              <td><button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteCity(Search)">Delete</button></td>
            </tr>
      </table>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. BTW I just started out with angular so please bear in mind I am not that skilled.

Answer (score 0):

So after many investigations I figured out where the exact issue was. As the error statement mentioned that it could only handle arrays and iterables. So we came to the conclusion to just make an array of the whole JSON.

So in the service:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
   const body = res.json();
   return body;
}
```

this had to become:

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
   const body = Array.of(res.json());
   return body;
}
```

This fixed the error and I could properly read out the JSON and copy the parameters to a local JSON file.